# LibGDX - Splash Screen isn't switching to a screen after it is clicked

Tags: java, libgdx

been stuck on this annoying issue for the past 1 - 2 hours already. Was wondering if someone could help me out. So I added a splash screen for my soon to be finished game. I was following this tutorial I found online http://www.caindev.com/2012/06/04/libgdx-splash-screen-image-tutorial.html it was exactly what I wanted. I needed a splash screen to load and stay until the user pressed the screen. I did everything the tutorial said to do but once the image from my splash screen is loaded it won't switch to my MainMenu screen when it's pressed the image just stays there frozen.

Here's my code for: MyGame

```
package com.jack.mygame;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.jack.MyGame.screens.GameScreen;
import com.jack.MyGame.splash.SplashScreen;

public class MyGame extends Game {

    public static int nWidth;
    public static int nHeight;
    private Game game; 

    public MyGame() {
        game = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        nWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        nHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

Here's my code for SplashScreen:

```
package com.jack.mygame.splash;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import static com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.gl;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.jack.mygame.MyGame;
import com.jack.MyGame.screens.MainMenu;

public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

    private Texture logo;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private MyGame game;

    public SplashScreen(MyGame game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        logo = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("logo.png"));
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float f) {
        handleInput();

        GL20 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL20();
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(logo, 0, 0, MyGame.nWidth, MyGame.nHeight);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    private void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int i, int i1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

}
```

Lastly, my code for the MainMenu:

```
package com.jack.mygame.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.jack.mygame.MyGame;

public class MainMenu implements Screen {

    private Game game;

    public MainMenu(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float f) {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int i, int i1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

}
```

Any help would be amazing. Haven't messed with screens in LibGDX before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code and for me it works. The only problem is that your MainMenu class does not render any view. So when you click splashscreen you are not refreshing what is displayed on screen. Add for example this code in MainMenu class to clear screen from your splashscreen logo:

```
@Override
public void render(float f) {
    GL20 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL20();
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I feel so dumb can't believe I forgot to add that.